# How to plot a covariance matrix on a 2D plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, octave, covariance, covariance-matrix

In MATLAB there is a function called `cov`. If I insert a matrix `X` into `cov` like this `cov(X)`, then `cov` will return a square matrix of covariance.

My question is very simple:
How can I, with MATLAB, plot that matrix `cov(X)` onto a `2D` plot like this.
I can see a lot of covariance matrix plots at Google. But how do they create them?

[image]

Comment: Is your matrix 2x2?

Comment: What do you mean by "plotting the matrix"? Do you mean that you want the eigenvectors pointing along the cloud, [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#/media/File:GaussianScatterPCA.svg)? If not, perhaps you could link to an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I don't really know. But I have seen people plotting a matrix as it was on a 2D plot. So I guess it's some kind of principal component.

Comment: @MrYui Again, it would be helpful if you could verify whether the link in my previous comment has the kind of plot that you're talking about and, if it is not, give another link that has the kind of graph you're looking for.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Here for example https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/

Comment: @MrYui Okay, so it seems like I was on the right track

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes! So in this case, you plot the columns of the covariance matrix `X`. I assume that the only way to display a 2D matrix at a 2D plot.

Comment: It is not the *only way* to display a matrix in a 2D plot, but it is the most common way to do so and it is a meaningful way to do so in this context.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I don't know how I can compare two matricies with each other. But with PCA, I can see the differences between two scatter plots. That's the reason why I asked this question. If I can compare two matricies with each other...some smart and robust way, then I have found my solution.

Comment: Well if you plot two matrices in this way, then you can indeed see the difference between them. Two covariant matrices will be the same if and only if they have the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: @BenGrossmann Hmm...can I see similarities between two covariance matrices even if they are not the same, by using eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Or should I use colleration matrices instead?

Comment: @MrYui Yes, that's right. Something similar with correlation matrices probably would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you're trying to add the principal components to the plot. To do that, you could do something like this.

```
%% generate data points

S_tru = [2 1; 1 1];
N = 1000;
%% compute mean, covariance, principal components
X = mvnrnd([0,0],S_tru,N);
mu = mean(X);
S = cov(X);
[U,D] = eig(S);

%% specify base points/directions for arrows
base = [mu;mu];
vecs = sqrt(D)*U';
vecs = 2 * vecs;

%% plot
plot(X(:,1),X(:,2), 'r.')
axis equal
hold on
quiver(base(:,1),base(:,2),vecs(:,1),vecs(:,2),'blue','LineWidth',2)
```

Resulting graph:

[image: covariance plot]

Comment: So you actually only plot two columns of covariance matrix `X`?

Comment: @MrYui The arrows being plotted are not the columns of `X`. Instead, these are the eigenvectors of `X`, scaled by the square root of the corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: But `X = mvnrnd([0,0],S_tru,N);` ?

Comment: @MrYui I misspoke, the covariance matrix of `X` is `S`; I plot the eigenvectors of *the covariance matrix of* `X`.

Comment: Yes, the red dots are `X` right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right